# Unable to compile code using cmath

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am attempting to use GLM to work with Vulkan/SDL. I have both of those working correctly, however when I select build, it says that

```
/usr/include/c++/7.1.1/cmath:45: error: math.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <math.h>
               ^~~~~~~~
```

However if I were to go into my project and just include it normally, it works fine. I tried using G++ instead of GCC. I'm on Linux(arch) and using QT Creator QT version 5.9.1 . I'm using Qmake, but no Qt libraries. The GLM code im using is

```
glm::mat4 matrix;
glm::vec4 vec;
auto test = matrix * vec;
```

and these are the includes

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

the compiler command line is:

```
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../SDLProject -I. -isystem /usr/local/include -I../VulkanSDK/1.0.54.0/x86_64/include -isystem /usr/include -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../SDLProject/main.cpp
```

Comment: Need more information. What type of project in QT, what version, some minimal code that illustrates the issue ?

Comment: What compile issues are you getting?

Comment: I updated the question with more code blocks.

Comment: What's the compiler command line?

Comment: Added the command line.

Comment: `#include_next` is really necessary?

Comment: That is just what it is in the <cmath> include. I did not put it there. I tried removing it and it threw a different error.

Comment: Also see Jonathan Wakely's [Why `<cstdlib>` is more complicated than you might think](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/) from the Red Hat blogs. Wakely is one of GCC's C++ standard library maintainers. I think `<math.h>` vs `<cmath>` is a much more interesting case study because of the three overloads for many functions (integral, float and long double).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own question. I realized that I had set an

```
INCLUDE_PATH+= /usr/include
```

That mistake is what caused #include_next to be unable to find the next include. After removing that from my .pro file, it compiled without a hiccup.